# Matplotlib savefig function not working in Spyder

Tags: python, matplotlib, spyder

I am using Spyder environment. After the plot, I have put the savefig function. But it is not saving the plots in the relevant folder.

A part of the code-

```
for t in range(1,int(TotT/dt)):
    plt.clf()

    v2_a=(dt*1E-15)*f(x2[-1],v2[-1])    # Heat Bath for site 2. Time step converted to fs.
    v2_b=(dt*1E-15)*f(x2[-1]+(dt*1E-15)*v2[-1],v2[-1]+v2_a)
    v2_next=v2[-1]+0.5*(v2_a+v2_b)

    x2_a=(dt*1E-15)*v2[-1]
    x2_b=(dt*1E-15)*(v2[-1]+v2_a)
    x2_next=x2[-1]+0.5*(x2_a+x2_b)

    v2.append(v2_next)
    x2.append(x2_next)

    E2=Lambda*x2[-1]

    prop_tdep=np.zeros([720,720],dtype=complex)

    np.fill_diagonal(prop_tdep[:360,:360],1)
    np.fill_diagonal(prop_tdep[360:,360:],np.exp(-1j*E2*dt/hbar))

    prop_1=np.matmul(prop_tdep,psi[:,t-1]) #First multiplication in time propagation 

    psi[:,t]=np.matmul(prop_0,prop_1)

    if t%int(1/dt)==0:
        plt.plot(prob_dens(np.fft.fftshift(psi[:360,t])),'xkcd:forest green')
        plt.title("Elapsed time = %s fs"%(t*dt))
        plt.xlabel("~Angular Momentum",size=18)
        plt.ylabel("Probability density",size=16)
        plt.tick_params(axis='both', labelsize=14,which='both')
        plt.tick_params(direction='in', length=7, width=1.1, colors='k',which='major')
        plt.tick_params(direction='in', length=4, width=1.1, colors='k',which='minor')
        #plt.axes().yaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(0.1))
        #plt.axes().xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(30))
        plt.savefig("FT_2states_dyn_withBath-%04d"%(t*dt))
        print((t*dt))
```

Comment: your working directory is probably not what you think it is, either do `%pwd` on the spyder terminal to see where you are or use a full path instead of a relative path in the `savefig`

Comment: I tried the %pwd command and showed me the exact directory where I want to save it.

Comment: try the full path just to be sure, im still suspicious

Comment: Tried   plt.savefig("/Users/atreyamajumdar/Desktop/Quantum Yield/FT_2states_dyn_withBath-%04d"%(t*dt)) Still has the same problem. Do you think it might be related to how spyder saves figures internally?

Answer (score 1):

You don't specify the format to save. You may either do that by appending it to the filename, such that it is recognized automatically

```
plt.savefig("filename.png")
```

or you may specify it as a parameter, if you don't want your file to carry the extension.

```
plt.savefig("filename", format="png")
```

Comment: That didn't help either.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `plt.close()` after `plt.savefig(...)` as suggested here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49165652/3745353) worked for me. I assume it opens a graphics device in the file but doesn't save it until it is closed in the IDE (similar to graphics devices in `R`).

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to assign the `plt.figure` call to a variable and then use the `show()`, `savefig()` and `clf()` methods for that specific instance of `plt.figure` like so:

```
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
fig1 = plt.figure(figsize=(3, 4))
ax = fig1.gca().axes
ax.plot([1,2], [3,9], '-k')
fig1.show()
fig1.savefig('/my/file/location.png', format='png', dpi=150)
fig1.clf()
```

You should be able to use an absolute or relative path.